# Geofences in Leaflet with live Location

Tags: leaflet, geolocation, angular, geofencing

I'm a newbie in terms of programming. I'm building a Web App with Angular and Leaflet, which has to locate the users position and notify him in case he is close to specific buildings. There are several threads dealing with how to detect if a marker is inside a circle/geofence with solutions similar to the following:

```
//fence is a L.circle
//userPos is a L.marker

var fencePos = fence.getLatLng();
var fenceRadius = fence.getRadius();

userPos.on('dragend', function (event) {
  userPos = event.target;
  var currentPos = userPos.getLatLng();

  if (currentPos.distanceTo(fencePos) <= fenceRadius) {
    fence.setStyle({
      fillColor: 'green'
    })
  } else {
    fence.setStyle({
      fillColor: 'grey'
    })
  }
})
```

The problem in my case is, that I don't know to what I have to listen, since I don't have a `dragend` event for live location data. My piece of code looks like this:

```
watchPosition() {
  let desLat = 0;
  let desLon = 0;
  let id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    (position) => {
      console.log(`lat: ${position.coords.latitude}, lon: ${position.coords.longitude}`);
      if (position.coords.latitude === desLat) {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
      }

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }, {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0,
    }
  )
};

ngOnInit() {
  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log('location is not supported');
  }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude
    var long = position.coords.longitude

    var userPosition = L.marker([lat, long], {
      icon: myIcon
    }).addTo(this.map);

    this.watchPosition();
  });
}
```

How can I implement something like in the beginning to my code? Each time `watchPosition` is triggered a function should measure if the `userPos` is inside one or more circles.

Comment: What are your `fencePos` coordinates in case of geolocation? Is this `[desLat, desLon]`? It seems to be `[0, 0]` all the time.

Comment: i dont know what deslat & deslong does, since i copied most of the code from a sample. I just needed watchPosition to have an update interval for the location. Therefore i do not have a fence/circle in my current code, since i did not know how to check if the marker is inside or not. Should i add it in watchPosition() ? Something like " for each circle in the array circles: if current Position is inside circle then ..." ? Could you provide me a solution?

Comment: There is not enough info in your question to suggest a solution. In what form is the data you want to use for checking the condition "within circle"? Array of coordinates? Layer with markers? Please edit your question and add that info.